# What is the mime-type of a wsdl file?

Tags: wsdl, mime-types

For example with a `png` file its `mime-type` is "image/png" ; so what is the mime-type for a `wsdl` file ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`text/xml` - WSDL is service description based on XML format.
You can see it in developer's tools, such as Firebug, in "Network" tab.

**UPD:** Although, wikipedia says that it should be `application/wsdl+xml`

Comment: Yes, there are few types with plus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type